# get Current user context

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, impersonation

I've got problems with running a powershellscript from different locations (c# application, webservice...).
I think it is a user context problem, so now I'm trying to find out under which user context powershell script is running.

**Is there any possibility log the current usercontext of the powershellscript?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to know the actual user:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement")
[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current
```

Use:

```
[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current | gm
```

to know available properties/methods of  `UserPrincipal`.

Answer (score 12):

You could use the [WindowsIdentity class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx) to get the current thread user:

```
[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
```

Comment: To add on, ```[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name``` will get you the specific user

Comment: Another easier command is: ```whoami```. This will also give you the current context user