# Programmatically getting credentials of a Scheduled Windows Task

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a program which I want to run as a scheduled windows task.
The windows task is predefined to run under a specific user account - credentials entered manually via the Scheduled Tasks UI.
Is there a way to programmatically get that predefined user's credentials (name, password and domain) when the program is initiated as a task, and use them for other purposes?

I've found several articles which explain how to create a task and "feed" it with credentials, but not the other way around. Is it even possible?

Comment: That sounds like a security violation to me.

Comment: No, but you can impersonate the user without knowing the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115686/get-current-user-context

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I basically want to be able to impersonate that user within my program. Don't see it necessarily as a security violation.

Comment: @Malk - this may be a good solution. I'll test it out and let you know. Would you like to post it as an answer?